# Ubuntu server 15.10 motd claims update

Tags: upgrade

```
7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

but `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` do not find anything.  `update-motd` also doesn't fix this.  Anyone know how to diagnose this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: interesting.  I thought 15.10 was the current farthest release, so dist-upgrade would not do anything until 16.04.  but it does...  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

doesn't install new versions. For a full upgrade you have to run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This command has nothing to do with an upgrade to the next Ubuntu release.

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer. Please accept with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: I had similar issue to OP and these commands fixed it.